# Why is this code leaking memory?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I am getting memory leak in following piece of code. I am allocating memory once and deleting it after my use. Can anyone explain what is going behind the scenes here that is causing a memory leak? Visual Studio is telling me there is a leak in this statement. If I remove these statements, leak is gone.

```
wxProcess *tmpProcess = new wxProcess();
tmpProcess->Redirect();
wxExecute(CmdToExecute, wxEXEC_SYNC, tmpProcess);           
wxExecute(CmdToExecute, wxEXEC_SYNC, tmpProcess);
delete tmpProcess;
```

I changed it to following and it is fine now as memory is then allocated on stack.

```
wxProcess tmpProcess1, tmpProcess2;
tmpProcess1.Redirect();
tmpProcess2.Redirect();
wxExecute(CmdToExecute, wxEXEC_SYNC, &tmpProcess1);
wxExecute(CmdToExecute, wxEXEC_SYNC, &tmpProcess2);
```

But still I would like to understand the problem in the first piece of code. Any insights on which code is better to have would be useful as well.

Comment: Pro-tip: Don't allocate on the heap if you can avoid it.

Comment: Well yes, in this case I can. But I would still like to know the problem with first code :)

Comment: You didn't actually mention what makes you think you have a memory leak. Did you crash? Did a tool tell you?

Comment: How did you determinate that the leak is in this exact piece of code?

Comment: Visual studio tells me there is a leak here. When I replace this by allocating memory on the stack, the leak is gone.

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't do that by default, how exactly do you know there is a leak.

Comment: One way that could leak is if you have exceptions thrown by the intermediate functions, you can avoid this by using smart pointers

Comment: The two code snippets are not equivalent. You're using two tmpProcess guys in the second one and maybe that's the reason for the leak. Maybe wxExecute does something bad

Comment: Adding to @KarthikT comment, try (no pun intended) and wrap the calls in that snippet in a `try` block and see if the complaint is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code seems fine, are you sure there is a memory leak or just increased memory usage ? If it is a leak then we will have to look into destructor of wxProcess, may be it is not freeing all the memory it allocated. It is also possible wxExecute throws some exception and not making it to the delete part of the code.

To avoid these, it is always a good idea to use RAII idiom when allocating memory in heap.

```
std::unique_ptr<wxProcess> tmpProcess(new wxProcess());
```